# Logical && operator

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

Having an unpredicted outcome using the `&&` logical operator. If I link more than 2 expressions, the `if` clause fails. Is there some limit to the number of expressions that can be concatenated using `&&`?

```
            if (tTellerProN.checked && tCareProN.checked && tSalesProN.checked) {
                $(flListEmpty).empty();
                $(flListEmpty).append($('<option></option>').val(0).html("Select Role"));
                $('.fl_list1 .list4').each(function (index) {
                    $(flListEmpty).append($('<option> </option>').val(index).html($(this).text()));
                })
            }
```

Comment: Retagged because `&&` belongs to javascript, not jQuery

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? Do you mean evaluates to false?

Comment: use braces:  `(` and `)` , to group && operations.

Comment: @c69 Good in practice but excess clutter if they are simple boolean values as in this situation.  If it was something like (x + y == 2) && (y + z == 6) then I would agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no limit. Your expression requires that all three `checked` values are `true`, otherwise it will return false. One of them must be `false` (or not `true`), that's why your `if` is failing.

For the record: `&&` is part of the javascript language, not the jQuery library.

Answer (score 4):

`&&` is not a jQuery operator, it is Javascript.  jQuery is a library that builds on Javascript.

I'm not sure what the `**` is in your IF statment but this code works:

```
var x = true;
var y = true;
var z = true;

alert(x && y && z);  // true
alert(x && y && !z); // false
```

I would alert the values of your 3 `.checked` parameters and make sure they are being set as you expected.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no limit.

However looking at your code (what little there is of it and with such descriptive variable names used), I would venture a guess that you actually mean `||`, not `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

i made a test case here with both && and ||: http://jsfiddle.net/VcmCM/